# Create a square block extrusion in sculpt?

Tags: sculpting

Newbie here. I am new to Blender, I am wondering is it possible(in sculpting mode), to model a square indent into the object.

Say I have a cylinder or a cube, and I want to extrude a small square region on  one of its surface(you can imagine this to be a building). It has a square window, and the window is slightly out of the building's wall plane. I hope to repeat this effect for every surface, and each surface will have three by three windows. I don't need the window to have perfectly sharp corners. It could be slightly rounded. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use multiple tools to achieve the effect, but I think the easiest is to use a stencil mapped texture with the shape of the window and a Layer brush. The height of the layer brush determines the depth of the effect. For best results, the sculpt plane should be "Area Plane" locked (ticking the lock icon next to the drop down menu).

Here is a rough picture with the settings:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to do this, the best is to use a texture as a kind of stencil. Here is a quick example.. (I am using a bolt alpha from [Eat3D's excellent free pack](http://eat3d.com/forum/tips-tricks-and-free-videos/110-free-custom-bolt-alphas).  Additionally, you can find some more lovely free alphas here to play with if need be from [Pixologic](http://pixologic.com/zbrush/downloadcenter/alpha/) under *INDUSTRIAL*.)

If you add the texture as a *Brush* texture and tweak the settings a bit you can get some nice hard edged extrusions or details on your models.

As I have it below, I have set the brush shape under *Curve* in the toolshelf to `MAX` *(the flat one)* and bumped the brush strength up to a bit to about `.350`. You can grab the pack and test it to see how it works, basically, the closer you get to white, the more the surface will be extruded so if you mix your shades you can get even more details. In your case, I am assuming a simple one will do so, just an image in the shape of a window with the frame in white or a shade of gray depending on what you need.

[image]

*I would edit this further but Psy-Fi has some more tips in his answer, you can refer to that for more information.*

Answer (score -2):

Yeah in sculpt mode you would have to use either the grab tool or the add clay tool and "extrude" until you get the desired look, then you would have to use the crease and smooth tools to smooth the edges and create those corners if you want them. Another easier way is to instead of sculpt it use edit mode and create loop cuts **CTRL + R** to out line the shape of the windows. After that take the window "faces" and extrude them inward or out ward.[image] this was my result using the later method and some mirror and array modifyers.

Comment: He did ask to do it in sculpt mode. This is a perfectly fine answer, it's just the right answer to the wrong problem. Please update it to match the question.

Comment: The first part was in sculpt then the later being in edit mode as an alternative.

Comment: Yes, but the focus of your question was on the edit mode part, and he specifically asked for a way to do it in sculpt mode.

Comment: Got it, sorry 'bout that. Just trying to provide other options.

Comment: That's fine, just make sure to make that point(using headers or lists or something)